# How to Scale this Image Rollover CSS UL Menu? Disappearing Images when Browser Scaled Down

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues with this dictionary menu I'm working on. They are image rollovers using one image file and a ul list. However, when I scale the browser down the letters will disappear. I would like the whole menu to just scale down smaller to fit the screen. How can this be done? After doing some searches someone said it's because of the float, what would need to be done to correct this issue from happening? 
You can see my menu here to see what I mean... https://cruxmagic.com/lexicon

Here's my List and CSS...
Thanks for any help you can provide!

```
<ul id="lettersan">
<li><a id="leta" href="#a">A</a></li>
<li><a id="letb" href="#b">B</a></li>
<li><a id="letc" href="#c">C</a></li>
<li><a id="letd" href="#d">D</a></li>
<li><a id="lete" href="#e">E</a></li>
<li><a id="letf" href="#f">F</a></li>
<li><a id="letg" href="#g">G</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
/* Start Main Menu */
#lettersan {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 129px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 15px 50px 0px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#lettersan li {
    float: left;
}
#lettersan a {
    display: block;
    height: 165px;
    background-image: url(https://cruxmagic.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Lexicon-Letters-A-N.gif);
    text-indent: -9999px;
    outline-style: none;
}
#leta {
    width: 110px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
#leta:hover {
    background-position: 0px -129px;
}
#letb {
    width: 107px;
    background-position: -110px 0px;
}
#letb:hover {
    background-position: -110px -129px;
}
#letc {
    width: 112px;
    background-position: -217px 0px;
}
#letc:hover {
    background-position: -217px -129px;
}
#letd {
    width: 108px;
    background-position: -329px 0px;
}
#letd:hover {
    background-position: -329px -129px;
}
#lete {
    width: 105px;
    background-position: -437px 0px;
}
#lete:hover {
    background-position: -437px -129px;
}
#letf {
    width: 102px;
    background-position: -542px 0px;
}
#letf:hover {
    background-position: -542px -129px;
}
#letg {
    width: 116px;
    background-position: -644px 0px;
}
#letg:hover {
    background-position: -644px -129px;
}
/* End Main Menu */
```

Answer (score 0):

1) remove height from ( `#lettersan` ).

2) and set this style ( `#lettersan li { float: left; height: 129px; overflow: hidden;}` ).

Note: set these style only at @media (min-width: 676px), which means for mobile only and it will not affect for desktop... :)